# Cant use colors other than the default ones when using shadedE​rrorBar in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, errorbar

So I tried to use raacampbell/shadedE​rrorBar but couldn't use it in the way I wanted with nice colors.
All I could do was just the ugly regular/default colors.
it did let me use :

```
ss = shadedErrorBar(x,tav,errbar,'lineProps','r','transparent',true,'patchSaturation',0.08);
```

but not

```
ss = shadedErrorBar(x,tav,errbar,'lineProps','#A62EF4','transparent',true,'patchSaturation',0.08);
```

hope someone can help, I like my graphs pretty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB colors are defined as triplet values for RGB and not in #A62EF4
So you need to convert hexadecimal A6, 2E and F4 into value from 0.0 ... 1.0. In decimal A6 = 166, 2E = 46, F4 = 244, so replace the 'r' (for red) by [166 46 244]/255